# Error in initialization of chrome browser in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I executed below script in selenium webdriver:

```
package Facebook;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class facebooklogin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }

}
```

Facing below error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path
>   to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver
>   system property; for more information, see
>   https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest
>   version can be downloaded from
>   http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html     at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:172)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:109)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$0(ChromeDriverService.java:1)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:290)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:116)
>     at Facebook.facebooklogin.main(facebooklogin.java:11)

Comment: read the exception mostly the part 'for more information see....;

Answer (score 1):

Please check your exception lines,  which is saying - `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;` 
Selenium can't communicate directly with browsers, it needs a driver file which is provided by the browser providers. Here in Chrome browsers when you want to run the script you'll require [chromedriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) basically provided by Google. Downlaod the driver file and put it in your project, and add below lines before browser initialization.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```